# Determining CDF of a function with variable inside absolute value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

[image]

On the final exam I had on probability I have had this question. In the question I don't understand, they ask for the CDF of $f_y(y)$, namely $F_y(y)$.

The solution is given as follows:

[image]

The issue I have with this solution is that I don't understand two things. Namely, why the intervals are split from $0 \leq y < 1$ and $1 \leq y \leq 2$. It would be logical in my eyes that the full interval would be uwes from $0 \leq y \leq 2$. How can I apply this split in other problems with different intervals?

Secondly, for the $0 \leq y < 1$ interval, they apply $P(|X| \leq y)$ which you can rewrite to $P(-y \leq X \leq y)$, which is equal to $F_x(y) - F_x(-y)$. And for the other interval I know that the CDF is the integral of the PDF, hence the $\frac{1}{9}(y+1)^2$. But why do they apply $F_x(y) - F_x(-y) $ on the one interval, but not the other.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @AnotherUser Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

Because if $y \geq 1$, $F_X(-y) = 0$, so it might be confusing to answer both intervals in the same manner. Indeed, you could take $F_X(y) - F_X(-y)$ in the whole interval [0,2], noting that in the interval (1,2] $F_Y(y) = F_X(y)-0$. Let's take $x\geq 1$, we have that
$$
P(|X|\leq x) = P(x\leq X\leq x) = \int_{-x}^{x}f_X(x)dx = \int_{-1}^{x}f_X(x)dx = F_X(x).
$$
because $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\leq -1$.

If $0 \leq x\leq 1$ then
$$
P(|X|\leq x) = P(x\leq X\leq x) = \int_{-x}^{x}f_X(x)dx = F_X(x)-F_X(-x).
$$
The author probably tried to avoid confusion by giving both "kinds" of answers.